Troubles sending binary file to rest API
I try send file to rest API, but service return error.
variables:
  l_amount    INTEGER := 100;
  l_pos       INTEGER := 1;
  i number;
  fSize      number; -- dbms_lob.getlength(myFile);
  contLength number; -- fSize + length of request body service information
  req       utl_http.req;
  resp      utl_http.resp;

code:
url := 'https://tstmock.free.beeceptor.com/test1'; --test mock service
req := utl_http.begin_request(url, 'POST');

lBoundary := '----------------------------1234567890';

utl_http.set_header(req, 'Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data;boundary='||lBoundary);
utl_http.set_header(req, 'Content-Length',contLength); 
utl_http.set_header(req, 'accept-encoding','gzip, deflate, br'); 
utl_http.set_header(req, 'accept','*/*'); 
utl_http.set_header(req,'user-agent','Mozila/4.0');
utl_http.write_raw(req, l_buffer);
WHILE l_pos < f_size LOOP
    dbms_lob.read(l_file, l_amount, l_pos, l_buffer);
    stdio.put_line_buf(l_buffer);
    utl_http.write_raw(req, l_buffer);
    l_pos := l_pos + l_amount;            
END LOOP;

request body:
----------------------------1234567890
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="test.zip"
Content-Type: application/zip

*here content of zip file* 
----------------------------1234567890--

this code work fine, and test mock server receive request normally. But!!! When i try send this file to https://file.io/ i receive error message:
answer code = 400 {"success":false,"name":"ApiError","code":"FILE_MISSING","message":"No file or text data found","status":400,"help":"https://file.io/help/api/errors/FILE_MISSING","key":null} 
when i try send this file from Postman utility, request body on free.beeceptor.com like as request from Oracle, but sending from Postman to https://file.io/ work fine.

Content-disposition should be declared in header.
